# How to test/validate unlabeled data in association rules in R?

Tags: machine-learning, r, cross-validation

I produced association rules by using the arules package (apriori). I'm left with +/- 250 rules. I would like to test/validate the rules that I have, like answering the question: How do I know that these association rules are true? How can I validate them? What are common practice to test it?

I thought about cross validation (with training data and test data) as I read that it's not impossible to use it on unsupervised learning methods..but I'm not sure if it makes sense since I don't use labeled data.

If someone has a clue, even if it's not specifically about association rules (but testing other unsupervised learning methods), that would also be helpful to me.

I uploaded an example of the data that I use here in case it's relevant: https://www.mediafire.com/?4b1zqpkbjf15iuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider using your own `APparameter` object to put "significance" constraints on the rules learned by Apriori. See page 13 of the [arules documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/arules.pdf). This could reduce the number of uninteresting rules returned in your run.

In lieu of gold standard data for your domain, consider bootstrap resampling as a form of validation, as described [in this article](http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00003198/01/lal.pdf).